# How to export array to csv in powershell?

Tags: powershell

```
$x1 = (1,22,333,4444)
$x1 | export-csv 'd:\123.csv' -Force
```

Then I get this:

[image]

How do I Get a table like this?:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CSV's don't just accept arbitrary data properly, you can use `| Out-File x.csv` to dump them out on individual lines, and then read it back in with `Import-Csv` specifying headers, but a proper CSV needs headers when it is saved.

if you want to save it out properly you need to convert it into an object where the numbers are actually "named" within an object so powershell can create a valid CSV.

```
1,22,333,4444 | ForEach {
    [PSCustomObject]@{Number = $_}
} | Export-Csv C:\++\123.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

`-NoTypeInformation` removes the `#TYPE` header.

that being said, `Out-File` is the only way it will match your 'expected' output table, you don't seem to be looking for a CSV here.

Answer (score 1):

This will create a proper csv file with a header:

```
ConvertFrom-Csv (1,22,333,4444) -Header Number|Export-Csv .\123.csv -NoType
```

Loaded in Excel cell A1 will be `Number`

This will create a fake Csv accepted by Excel and returning your sample table.

```
 (1,22,333,4444)|Set-Content .\234.csv
```